# Deleted a file by mistake, how to get from origin master?

Tags: git

I deleted a file on my desktop by mistake, how can I get it from the remote master?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
git checkout -- /path/to/file
```

should be enough to restore it, since you have a local repo with that file in it.
That would restore your file at the version of the file present in the index.
(i.e. the last version you ran `git add` on it).

To restore it at the latest commit of your current branch:

```
git checkout HEAD -- /path/to/file
```